# PHPExcel getHighestColumn() not working

Tags: php, phpexcel

Rather than defining cell color etc. in a range in the form of "A1:G1" or range('A','G') - since the table is dynamic and will have different count of columns each time - I wanted to use the range in the form of:

```
->getStyle('A1:' . $highestColumn . '1')
```

where

```
 $highestColumn = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestColumn();
```

but this is not working. If I print the result, $highestColumn is shown to be "A", whereas in fact it should be "G".

Why is getHighestColumn() not working?

Comment: I can't even begin to guess.... perhaps your "active" sheet is an empty worksheet

Comment: Is this a file that you're loading? Are you creating a new PHPExcel object yourself? Have you done any debugging to see what is in row 1?

Comment: It's a file I am creating.It works fine if I simply use manual range like A1:G1 -- the XLSX file is created and formatted and everything is nice and dandy.

Answer (score 2):

FIXED IT.

Just took all the code which I was using for formatting etc. and MOVED it below the statement **$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)** right before the file is saved.

And I used this as the variable:

```
$highestColumn = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestDataColumn();
```

Answer (score 1):

`getHighestColumn()` (and `getHighestRow()`) use a value populated from a file load, and those values then remain unchanged - even if you add further rows or columns yourself - until you save the PHPExcel object.

Perhaps you should use `getHighestDataColumn()` which is calculated dynamically at the point when it is called, and always based on the actual collection of cell data at that point in time.

Comment: Tried that as well. It still shows "A" ... instead of "G".

So, my range (A1:$highestColumn1) of course won't work properly because then it takes the range A1:A1 --- which is only one cell, instead of A1:G1